# Getting error "Specified method is not supported." on bitmap.save in c#. CaptchaMvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, captcha

[image]

Getting error like "Specified method is not supported".

```
Validate.ArgumentNotNull(response, "response");
Validate.ArgumentNotNull(drawingModel, "drawingModel");
using (Bitmap bitmap = CaptchaUtils.ImageGeneratorFactory(drawingModel).Generate(drawingModel))
{
   response.ContentType = "image/gif";
   bitmap.Save(response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
}
```

I am stuck in that. Please help to resolve this error. Let me know if you want more info regarding this issue.

Comment: `response.OutputStream` is a compressed stream?

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya: no

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have already written in this stream.

Try to do

```
response.Clear();
```

beforehand.

If something was already written in the stream, you will try to write at the end of the stream.

And you cannot set position for `System.Web.HttpResponse.OutputStream` stream, because it is not seekable

Answer (score 0):

Issue was faced in CaptchaMvc(Mvc 5), finally it has been resolved. 
For future if any one face this issue than below is the solution you can try it:

```
using (Bitmap image = CaptchaUtils.ImageGeneratorFactory(drawingModel).Generate(drawingModel))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```